# Immigrating to Canada without a Degree and with EUR

Tags: visa, germany, canada

I today live in Germany, but I am strongly considering to move to Canada.

I know there are other question regarding the degree, but my situation is a bit different.

- I am a Software Developer.
- 7 years of Experience
- One year of College Diploma in my Field(not a bachelor's degree)
- 10.000 EUR in an account (no Canadian Dollars)
- I got the highest score in IELTS
- I am 28 years old

Do I need to buy Canadian Dollars or the account with EUR should be enough?

what are my chances under my conditions?

Comment: Get a job offer, that should help.

Comment: Preferably, a job offer from a company that is used to dealing with Canadian immigration for employees.

Comment: For Express Entry, without a job offer or a provincial nomination, you don't have enough points.

Comment: Nobody cares what currency you hold.  It's easy to change money.